# Android Studio finished with non-zero exit value 1 after adding module

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have the problem after adding module in `gradle` file.

Earlier I have following structure of my project

```
---app (main module)
---customview (dependency module add as `compile project` into the main module gradle file) 
---daogenerator (separate module)
```

Daogenerator module was used as separate module to generate dao classes and model classes by `Greendao` library.

Everything was fine, but one problem that I should duplicate some common lets say `Contract classes` in both modules, so I decided to optimize and have only one file.
And as far as I cannot use classes from different modules if there are not specified in the `gradle` file as dependency.
So I added this line into my `gradle` file in the `app` module

```
compile project(':daogenerator')
```

After that I successfully imported common class but failed to compile the project. I got

```
finished with non-zero exit value 1 .....
```

Nothing more about the problem.

What I have already tried to do

1. Clean/Rebuild
2. Add `dexOptions {
       javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
       jumboMode true
       incremental true
   }` to the main app `gradle` file
3. Invalidate & Restart
4. Run `./gradlew assembleDebug --info` got

> Successfully started process 'command
>   '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' PREDEX CACHE HITS:   0 PREDEX
>   CACHE MISSES: 1 Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s). Could not read standard
>   output of: command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'.
>   java.io.IOException: Stream closed
>           at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)

I have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this was my fault. I have forgotten that `GreenDao` library is simple java application it has entry point `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception`

So it doesn't make any sense to compile it together with android application